# Generators for $\mathbb{Z_n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, integers, cyclic-groups

I would like to show that  $K$ is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}_n$ $\iff$ $\gcd(K,n)=1$ and $1 \leq K <n$.

My Attempt:

Assume $\gcd(K,n)=1$ and $1 \leq K <n$. That means $K \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ and so it suffices to show that $\mathbb{Z}_n\subset \langle K\rangle$ . Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ be arbitrary and so by bezouts lemma, there exists integers $a,b$  such that $aK+yn=1$, hence $x=x^{aK+yn}=x^{aK}$ (since $\mathbb{Z}_n$ under addition is cyclic). But $x^{aK}=(aK)x=(ax)K$ and so $x \in \langle K\rangle$. Is this proof so far correct? How would I prove the other direction?

Answer (score 1):

It seems correct, yes. For the other direction I'd suggest contrapositive. If $\text{gcd}(K,n)=m,$ then $$\text{lcm}(K,n)=Kn/m=K(n/m),$$ so $K$ has order $n/m,$ and $\left<K\right>$ has $n/m$ elements. So if $m\not=1,$ then $\left<K\right>$ has less than $n$ elements, and $\left<K\right>\not=\mathbb{Z}_n.$

Comment: I'm not sure why it would have to have order n\m, may you please clarify?

Comment: Look at $K,K2,K3,...,K(n/m).$ The only term in this list that is congruent to $0$ modulo $n$ is $K(n/m),$ as $K(n/m)$ is the least common multiple of $K$ and $n.$ This is exactly what it means for $K$ to have order $n/m$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n.$

Comment: Can't I just prove it by saying assume there is another integer r such that $Kr=0$ and the $Kr=K(n/m)$ and so $r= (n/m)$?

Comment: No, it's more nuanced than that. Like, $4\cdot 2\equiv 0(\mod 8)$ and $4\cdot 4\equiv 0(\mod 8),$ but $4\not\equiv 2(\mod 8).$ You could show it by assuming that $1\leq r\leq n/m,$ and then since $n/m$ is the least common multiple deducing that $r=n/m,$ but that's essentially what I said in other words.

Comment: Haha, Idk why but it doesn't seem very intuitive.

Comment: It's probably the fact that we're working with a ring with zero-divisors. The familiar property of the integers that $Kr=k(n/m)$ implies $r=(n/m)$ holds because the integers have no zero divisors. However, $\mathbb{Z}_n$ has zero divisors whenever $n$ is not prime, so the familiar intuition (cancellation laws) break down.

Comment: so what would be a necessary condition in general for the property in $Z_n$ to hold?

Comment: Well, in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ it would hold that $Kr=K(n/m)$ implies $r=n/m$ if and only if $K$ was not a zero divisor, which happens if and only if $\text{gcd}(K,n)=1.$